# How to echo brief directory in batch

Tags: batch-file

A simple example:

```
set path=C:\ONE\TWO\..\
ECHO %path%
```

It will display `C:\ONE\TWO\..\..\` How to display a brief path `C:\ONE\`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set _path=C:\ONE\TWO\..\
::ECHO %_path%

pushd %_path%
echo %cd%
popd
```

And don't overwrite the `%PATH%` variable. It is too important to be touched like that.Here I've used `_path`

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to use a FOR command.

```
set _path=C:\ONE\TWO\..\
for %%G in ("%_path%") do echo %%~dpG
```

Comment: With `set _path=C:\ONE\TWO\THREE\..` returns `C:\ONE\ `. Use of variable `%%~fG` instead of `%%~dpG` returns `C:\ONE\TWO` . Seems the `f` modifier is more reliable. Added space behind the result as site is escaping the tick with the backslash.